How to disable enableEdgeToEdge() automatically generated when creating new activity
Recently whenever I create new activity it always generate edgetoedge code like this:
class BonDetail : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.bon_detail)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
    }
}

which I can just delete the line just fine but the problem is it also add this line into my gradle
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.9.1'

and because of that broke my current app. because I assume it conflict with implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
this is what my current gradle looks like:
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'

    //MATERIAL DESIGN 
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.9.1' <-- this is automatically added whenever I create new activity

This is an old project but I don't want to change many things in the project since many of our client still use old android like 5.0 or 6.0.
I just want to prevent Android Studio to automatically change my gradle with this edgetoedge thing, anyone know how to do this?

Edge-to-edge has become an requirement in Android 15. Google will soon enforce apps updates to target Android 15 in one or two years and hence enforce edge-to-edge implementation. If you are planning to keep maintaining your app in the future, you HAVE TO implement edge-to-edge properly. That's why the include it in the boilerplate.

@RickyMo thanks for the reply, I agree 100%, but this project is only used in our workplace and can only be downloaded via our website and not from Playstore so I don't think Google enforcement will apply to us.
While I do want to keep maintaining it I will only use a feature that is always compatible with older Android since many of our employees are using a very old phone


Recently whenever I create new activity it always generate edgetoedge code like this

Presumably, you chose to use the new-activity wizard, and the particular template that you chose in that wizard uses this code and that dependency.

I just want to prevent Android Studio to automatically change my gradle with this edgetoedge thing, anyone know how to do this?

Do not use the new-activity wizard. Create the Activity subclass and its <activity> manifest entry manually.

I didn't think of that. pretty troublesome but a beggar can't be chooser I guess. thanks for the advice

That sounds like more work than clicking in the new activity wizard then delete 2 lines you don't want. Maybe write a shell script to automate it if really need to do it frequently.

Unfortunately, Google never opened up the templating system that powers those wizards. That was a lost opportunity, IMHO.
